# Liveagent Stateless Chat - Persistent Chat

Tags: visualforce, liveagent

Does anyone implemented a custom visualforce chat and was able to make it persistent? chat not disconnecting on page navigate/refresh?

Answer (score 0):

(I am considering you know liveagent deployment and embedded service deployment)
You can create 2 different VF pages example test1 and test2.
Create an embedded service and copy the system generated code snippet.

Paste the same code on both of these pages.
Provide the link of page 1 to page 2 and page 2 to page 1.

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/test1">Next Page</apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/test2">Previous Page</apex:outputLink>
```

Save and launch the Vf pages.
Start the chat in test1.
Navigate to test2 from the link.
You can see you can continue with the previous conversation.
The chat is persistent.

Comment: what I'm trying to figure out is the custom visualforce chat I've embedded to my web page..at the moment, I only know 2 ways of embedding a vf chat to an external web page, one is is through iframe, 2nd is by opening the chat to separate pop-up window/tab.. the latter is not an option for me at the moment...
I'm trying to figure out not to reload the iframe when a user navigate to a different page in my webpage/...